# Why doesn't this redirect to /dev/null?

Tags: bash, pipe, stderr

Perhaps it's just late and I'm having brain farts but shouldn't this

```
(>&2 echo dying) 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

produce no output in a normal shell?

Similarly if this is `/tmp/x.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
die "dying"
```

Then why does this

```
#> perl /tmp/x.pl 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

output

```
dying at /tmp/x.pl line 2.
```

?

Comment: This is, incidentally, [BashFAQ #55](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055).

Comment: It's also common enough that [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) has [a warning](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2069) for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirections are processed left-to-right. So you're doing `2>&1` *before* you do `>/dev/null`. This redirects FD 2 to the original connection of FD 1 (presumably the terminal), then redirects FD 1 to `/dev/null`. FD 2 is still connected to the terminal.

To redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`, you have to use

```
(>&2 echo dying) >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

The order in which file descriptor redirections is done is very important.

Just switch the orders:

```
(>&2 echo dying) >/dev/null 2>&1
perl /tmp/x.pl >/dev/null 2>&1
```

While you are doing:

```
(>&2 echo dying) 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

the STDOUT of subshell (`()`) is redirected to where STDERR of the subshell is first. Then in the parent (main) shell, you have redirected STDERR to STDOUT, which is pointing to the terminal at that moment, so the STDERR from the subshell will get printed, then you are redirecting STDOUT to `/dev/null` which will send STDOUT to `/dev/null` from that time of evaluation, not before.

Similar note goes for the second case too.

So, always maintain order while manipulation file descriptors, and the order of evaluation if from left to right.